# Web template resource file examples

Tags: web-template, localization, resource-files

Using resource files for Web Template:

1. How to add a localized Title to a list instance?
2. How to add a localized Title to a web part added in ONET.XML?
3. how to add localized terms in a CEWP contents added in ONET.XML?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the mapped folder called `RESOURCES` to you solution and then add you resx files there.

If you want to add your resx files in the App_GlobalResource folder in the IIS, then add an `Empty Element` to you solution, add your resx files to that and modify the SharePointSolutionItem.spdata to target the App_GlobalResource folder like so:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> 
<ProjectItem Type="Microsoft.VisualStudio.SharePoint.GenericElement" DefaultFile="Elements.xml" SupportedTrustLevels="All" SupportedDeploymentScopes="Web, Site, WebApplication, Farm, Package" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/2010/SharePointTools/SharePointProjectItemModel"> 
<Files> 
 <ProjectItemFile Source="Elements.xml" Target="App_GlobalResources\" Type="ElementManifest" /> 
 <ProjectItemFile Source="..\Resources\Contoso.resx" Type="AppGlobalResource"/>
 </Files> 
</ProjectItem>
```

Then make sure there is a Feature which contains that `Empty Element` and that the Feature has its scope to WebApplication.

Comment: How to reference those resources in the example cases?

Comment: @thomius `<property name="Title" type="string">$Resources:Contoso, MyWebPartTitle;</property>`

Comment: How the example 3: contents of CEWP? (or is it the same)

Comment: @thomius `<Content xmlns="//schemas.microsoft.com/WebPart/v2/ContentEditor">$Resources:Contoso, MyCEWPText;</Content>`

Answer (score 1):

Create new "Import SharePoint Solution Package" from Installed templates project and select your web template that you import from sharepoint than add resource file to your solution:

- add Resource File project items to your project. If you do not have
  to localize code in addition to the markup, you can instead add
  Global Resources Files.
- Provide a name for the default language resource file.
- Give the localized resource files the same name appended with the
  language-specific culture ID. For example, MyAppResources.de-DE.resx
  for German and MyAppResources.ja-JP.resx for Japanese.
- Set the Deployment Type property of each resource file to
  AppGlobalResource. This causes the resource files to deploy to the
  App_GlobalResources folder, where they are available to all ASPX
  pages and controls in the solution. The App_GlobalResources folder is
  located in C:\inetpub\wwwroot\wss\VirtualDirectories\\App_GlobalResources.
  Then replace all string in all artifacts(list, modules, pages..) to use your new resource file. Examples how to localize list instances, web parts you can find using this [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff955226%28v=office.14%29.aspx).

Comment: How to reference those resources in the example cases?

Comment: For example for list instance name: Name="$Resources:MyResources,ListInstance_News"
MyResources - name of the resources file (as described below) ListInstance_News - the resource entry

And the name of Resources file (for the entry above) for English should be:

MyResources.en-US.resx